# How to use FBSimulatorControl

Tags: ios, xcode7, ui-testing

I can now link FBSimulatorControl into my own OSX app and boot multiple simulators from there. I now want to run my UI Test code in these simulators like in this video link. http://adventuresinautomation.blogspot.com.au/2015/09/seconf2015-notes-from-simon-stewarts.html.

I could not find any documentation about how to do exactly like them, to boost multiple simulators and then run each of my test cases on all of them. I also would like to see how to run it with xcode7 UIAutomation Testing